# htaccess - Redirect dumb url to working url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos7, httpd.conf

I have the following `.htaccess` file that hides `.php` extension. That is, instead of showing `http://address/info.php`, it shows `http://address/info`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

In `htaccess` file I need to add that `phpinformation` (which is dumb link - doesn't go anywhere: `http://address/phpinformation`) redirects to `info`. That is, `http://address/phpinformation` needs to be redirected to `http://address/info`

How should I modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.120 
RewriteRule ^phpinformation\.php /info.php [R,NC,L] 
RewriteBase / 
## hide .php extension 
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC] 
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Redirect 301 //phpinformation http ://www.yoursite.com/info

Comment: Where you put it after or before rules?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Redirect 301 /phpinformation http://address/info
Where should be this  last line?

Comment: ... it is the last line.

Comment: Can you try to redirect to address/info.php

Comment: Still nothing with info.php.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !address.com/phpinformation.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://address.com/info.php$1 [L,R=301]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Now I am getting new error: "The page isn’t redirecting properly".  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.120/info.php$1 [L,R=301] 
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC] 
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/?phpinformation.php$ /info.php$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase / 
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC] 
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Now, when I run "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation", it gives me an error: "The page isn’t redirecting properly". "http://192.168.1.120/info" is working.

Comment: Okey just try to remove .php from phpinformation and from info at the redirect line and if you comes to phpinformation you will be redirect to info

Comment: Still the same error. Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?phpinformation$ /info$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews # Turn mod_rewrite on RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^phpinformation.php$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/info.php [R=301,L]
RewriteBase / 
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
 ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: If you go to 192.168.1.120/phpinformation.php you should be redirect to 192.168.1.120/info.php Are you getting a error?

Comment: Now it is "Internal Server Error" again.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews # Turn mod_rewrite on RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.120
RewriteRule ^phpinformation.php /info.php [R,NC,L]
RewriteBase / 
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
 ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Now, when calling "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation" it redirects successfully to "http://192.168.1.120/info" (Big thanks). But when trying to call ""http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation".php", it gives the error "problem loading page". Is this expected, because "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation.php" should lead anywhere (that url doesn't exist)? Should it work like ""http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation" works? Please explain why "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation.php" doesn't work and "http://192.168.1.120/info.php" successfully redirects to "http://192.168.1.120/info".

Comment: please try with this ^phpinformation\.php Are you have error?

Comment: I am getting an error on "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation.php", but "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation" is working. Why is that?

Comment: I have figured it out. Feel free to edit your answer and I will accept it.